# less is not defined within head

Tags: javascript, css, less

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');
        less.refreshStyles();
    });

</script>
```

I try to use this code http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/Yns9P/ but my console say less is not defined, happening at the line of `less.refreshStyles();`. I also tried to include it at the body, still giving me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure, the less.min.js is really loaded? My minimal fiddle works with your resource. http://jsfiddle.net/61qvvzha/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "Less is not defined" issue trying to get that exact code to work locally. I was also looking at the jsfiddle from [this](https://medium.com/@andsens/radial-progress-indicator-using-css-a917b80c43f9) tutorial on radial progress bars with CSS.

After wrestling my way through the tutorial again to try and find what I missed I came across the authors [GIT](https://github.com/andsens/blog-material/tree/master/radial-progress) for the tutorial blog.

I don't know much about Less, I was just tinkering around.

[Here](https://github.com/andsens/blog-material/blob/master/radial-progress/step_10.html) is code that got things running in the end.
So it seems like I missed the tag:

```
<style type="text/less><style>
```

Here is the full code from the git page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/less">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic);
.radial-progress {
    @circle-size: 120px;
    @circle-background: #d6dadc;
    @circle-color: #97a71d;
    @inset-size: 90px;
    @inset-color: #fbfbfb;
    @transition-length: 1s;
    @shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    @percentage-color: #97a71d;
    @percentage-font-size: 22px;
    @percentage-text-width: 57px;
    margin: 50px;
    width:  @circle-size;
    height: @circle-size;
    background-color: @circle-background;
    border-radius: 50%;
    .circle {
        .mask, .fill, .shadow {
            width:    @circle-size;
            height:   @circle-size;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: @shadow inset;
        }
        .mask, .fill {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            transition: -webkit-transform @transition-length;
            transition: -ms-transform @transition-length;
            transition: transform @transition-length;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .mask {
            clip: rect(0px, @circle-size, @circle-size, @circle-size/2);
            .fill {
                clip: rect(0px, @circle-size/2, @circle-size, 0px);
                background-color: @circle-color;
            }
        }
    }
    .inset {
        width:       @inset-size;
        height:      @inset-size;
        position:    absolute;
        margin-left: (@circle-size - @inset-size)/2;
        margin-top:  (@circle-size - @inset-size)/2;
        background-color: @inset-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: @shadow;
        .percentage {
            height:   @percentage-font-size;
            width:    @percentage-text-width;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top:      (@inset-size - @percentage-font-size) / 2;
            left:     (@inset-size - @percentage-text-width) / 2;
            line-height: 1;
            .numbers {
                margin-top: -@percentage-font-size;
                transition: width @transition-length;
                span {
                    width:          @percentage-text-width;
                    display:        inline-block;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    text-align:     center;
                    font-weight:    800;
                    font-size:      @percentage-font-size;
                    font-family:    "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    color:          @percentage-color;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @i: 0;
    @increment: 180deg / 100;
    .loop (@i) when (@i <= 100) {
        &[data-progress="@{i}"] {
            .circle {
                .mask.full, .fill {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                    transform: rotate(@increment * @i);
                }   
                .fill.fix {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                    transform: rotate(@increment * @i * 2);
                }
            }
            .inset .percentage .numbers {
                width: @i * @percentage-text-width + @percentage-text-width;
            }
        }
        .loop(@i + 1);
    }
    .loop(@i);
}
    </style>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
window.randomize = function() {
    $('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
setTimeout(window.randomize, 200);
$('.radial-progress').click(window.randomize);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
Animate percentage
<div class="radial-progress" data-progress="0">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="mask full">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask half">
            <div class="fill"></div>
            <div class="fill fix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inset">
        <div class="percentage">
            <div class="numbers"><span>-</span><span>0%</span><span>1%</span><span>2%</span><span>3%</span><span>4%</span><span>5%</span><span>6%</span><span>7%</span><span>8%</span><span>9%</span><span>10%</span><span>11%</span><span>12%</span><span>13%</span><span>14%</span><span>15%</span><span>16%</span><span>17%</span><span>18%</span><span>19%</span><span>20%</span><span>21%</span><span>22%</span><span>23%</span><span>24%</span><span>25%</span><span>26%</span><span>27%</span><span>28%</span><span>29%</span><span>30%</span><span>31%</span><span>32%</span><span>33%</span><span>34%</span><span>35%</span><span>36%</span><span>37%</span><span>38%</span><span>39%</span><span>40%</span><span>41%</span><span>42%</span><span>43%</span><span>44%</span><span>45%</span><span>46%</span><span>47%</span><span>48%</span><span>49%</span><span>50%</span><span>51%</span><span>52%</span><span>53%</span><span>54%</span><span>55%</span><span>56%</span><span>57%</span><span>58%</span><span>59%</span><span>60%</span><span>61%</span><span>62%</span><span>63%</span><span>64%</span><span>65%</span><span>66%</span><span>67%</span><span>68%</span><span>69%</span><span>70%</span><span>71%</span><span>72%</span><span>73%</span><span>74%</span><span>75%</span><span>76%</span><span>77%</span><span>78%</span><span>79%</span><span>80%</span><span>81%</span><span>82%</span><span>83%</span><span>84%</span><span>85%</span><span>86%</span><span>87%</span><span>88%</span><span>89%</span><span>90%</span><span>91%</span><span>92%</span><span>93%</span><span>94%</span><span>95%</span><span>96%</span><span>97%</span><span>98%</span><span>99%</span><span>100%</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.